# Accessing element with ID that contains "." character

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to access elements using jquery `$('#elementID')` method.
If any element contain **"."** character like

```
id="element.0" 
id="element.1"
```

i can't access that element.

Is it because of the **"."** character in id string ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the dot with `\\`

```
$('element\\.0');
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 7):

It would look like this for the first one:

```
$("#element\\.0")
```

*However*, even though this is valid (thanks to @[patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113716/patrick-dw) on the link below, I had my specs mixed up), you might want to consider a different delimiter, like a `-`, for example `id="element-0"`...it'll result in much cleaner/less problematic code (since class selectors use `.`).

Comment: Nick - I'm pretty sure a `.` is valid, just not often used because it also denotes a class in CSS. From HTML 4: `ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").` http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id

Comment: @patrick - Thanks patrick, I completely missed that `.` was valid...I always avoid it because of selector issues like this.  I'm not sure whether it's good or not that anything's fair game in HTML5 as long as they're unique.